# How to view actual dependency using IntelliJ Diagrams?

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, intellij-plugin

I am trying to create a UML for firefox focus: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/org/mozilla/focus

I imported the project into IntelliJ. I then right-clicked the `focus` folder and created a class diagram for it. It shows that the `widget` package depends on the `utils` package. Is there a way for me to see what exactly the `widget` package is using from the `utils` package?

Comment: Try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dsm-analysis.html .